# How to display document image preview in iOS app?

Tags: swift, preview, quicklook

I need to display document image preview. I have smth like messenger app and I want the user can see UIImage preview before opening document. Documents can be in doc, docx, docm, pptx, ppt, rtf formats.

I tried to use QuickLook library it can open that files but not generating preview UIImage from MS Office formats. I did that:

```
private func generatePreviewImage(for documentURL: URL?) -> UIImage? {
        guard let documentURL = documentURL else { return nil }
        let previewGenerator = QLThumbnailGenerator.shared
        let thumbnailSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)

        let request = QLThumbnailGenerator.Request(fileAt: documentURL, size: thumbnailSize, scale: UIScreen.main.scale, representationTypes: .lowQualityThumbnail)

        var thumbnail: UIImage?
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

        previewGenerator.generateRepresentations(for: request) { thumbnailRep, _, error in
            if let thumbnailImage = thumbnailRep?.uiImage {
                thumbnail = thumbnailImage
            }

            semaphore.signal()
        }

        semaphore.wait()
        return thumbnail
    }
```

This works but only for not MS Office formats.

Comment: Office thumbnails are not supported yet on iOS (previews are). Please file a feedback.